# XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly, the logs looks fine doesnt have any error i guess

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got an error like this after starting mysql

> 11.56.08  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 11.56.08  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

And this is the log

> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows
> interlocked functions
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
> size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
> buffer pool
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments
> are active.
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
> temporary tables
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
> 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
> file full; Please wait ...
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
> size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence
> number 1604020; transaction id 9
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
> C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at
> 200413 12:09:51
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2020-04-13 12:09:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

The log looks fine, and I don't see any trouble there.
I've tried all the tips on the Internet like deleting
ibdata1, ib_lofile1, ib_logfile0, etc, but still it doesn't fix the problem for me.

Any help?

Comment: Is this a new setup?

Comment: idk man, old employee just gave me this computer and didnt mention anything before he left

Comment: if the db is working db, and you've deleted ibdata1 (hopefully you have backup)... but if its not, just re-install a new one